# Get self instance inside interface implementation

Tags: java, android

I'm new to java/android.

I have an service class that have 2 methods.... prepare() and execute()..

both are async calls, so what I have to do is, call prepare() and wait for prepareFinished I'm listen to.... when the prepare method is finished, for the same service instance I'd like to call execute() method.....

Follow my try below:

```
for(int idx = 0; idx < services.length; idx++)
{
    MyService instance = services[idx];
    instance.setDataReadListener(new AsyncDataReadListener() {
        @Override
        public void prepareFinished(ServiceInfo info) {

           //I would like to get the self instannce here to call another 
                       //method after been prepared. something like::: sender.execute()

        }
    });
}

//In a button click I call above,  for each service its prepared I would like another method of the same service instance to be called:
for(int idx = 0; idx < services.length; idx++)
{
    MyService instance = services[idx];
    //async call
    instance.prepare();
}
```

How can I accomplish it?

Tks.

Answer (score 0):

Make instance final:

```
final MyService instance = services[idx];
```

and you can call `instance.execute()` inside `prepareFinished`.

Answer (score 0):

Make `instance` `final` and reference it directly:

```
for(int idx = 0; idx < services.length; idx++)
{
    final MyService instance = services[idx];
    instance.setDataReadListener(new AsyncDataReadListener() {
        @Override
        public void prepareFinished(ServiceInfo info) {
            instance.execute()
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with this approach?

```
final MyService instance = services[idx];
instance.setDataReadListener(new AsyncDataReadListener() {
    @Override
    public void prepareFinished(ServiceInfo info) {

       instance.execute();
    }
});
```